# FInding the number of matched keywords in text index in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Sample collection "test", (with text index on field1, field2, field3)  :

```
/* Item 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6011862888de9cd2347828e6"),
    "field1" : "Denver Segment1",
    "field2" : "student1 zero1",
    "field3" : "cat2 dog0"
}
/* Item 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6011866b88de9cd234782906"),
    "field1" : "meow cap",
    "field2" : "teacher eleven1",
    "field3" : "cat2 cow"
}

/* Item 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6011868b88de9cd234782909"),
    "field1" : "bark cake",
    "field2" : "admin hey",
    "field3" : "bird chirp"
}
```

And I am trying to sort the records based on number of keywords matched.
I have the following query (keywords are cat2 and student1)

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
   { $text: { $search: "cat2 student1" } },
   { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
```

The result is the following:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6011862888de9cd2347828e6"),
    "field1" : "Denver Segment1",
    "field2" : "student1 zero1",
    "field3" : "cat2 dog0",
    "score" : 1.5
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6011866b88de9cd234782906"),
    "field1" : "meow cap",
    "field2" : "teacher eleven1",
    "field3" : "cat2 cow",
    "score" : 0.75
}
```

This is fine, but I do not how to get the actually keywords shown as well.
For example expected result should be the following:

````
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6011862888de9cd2347828e6"),
    "field1" : "Denver Segment1",
    "field2" : "student1 zero1",
    "field3" : "cat2 dog0",
    "score" : 1.5,
    "matched-keywords":["cat2","student1"]

}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6011866b88de9cd234782906"),
    "field1" : "meow cap",
    "field2" : "teacher eleven1",
    "field3" : "cat2 cow",
    "score" : 0.75,
    "matched-keywords":["cat2"]

}
```

How can I do this ?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the aggregation pipeline you can achieve the result you are looking for.

**Stages:**

1. Text search.
2. Sort by descending score, use the $meta aggregation expression in the $sort stage.
3. [Split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/index.html) it and add a new field called matched-keywords.
4. Filter the matched-keywords using the [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/index.html).

.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$text": {
        "$search": "cat2 cow"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      score: {
        "$meta": "textScore"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "matched-keywords": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          {
            "$split": [
              "$field1",
              " "
            ]
          },
          {
            "$split": [
              "$field2",
              " "
            ]
          },
          {
            "$split": [
              "$field3",
              " "
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "matched-keywords": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$matched-keywords",
          "as": "word",
          "cond": {
            "$regexMatch": {
              "input": "cat2 cow",
              "regex": "$$word"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "field1": "Denver Segment1",
    "field2": "student1 zero1",
    "field3": "cat2 dog0",
    "matched-keywords": [
      "cat2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "field1": "meow cap",
    "field2": "teacher eleven1",
    "field3": "cat2 cow",
    "matched-keywords": [
      "cat2",
      "cow"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Haniel, I tried your solution for a single field, it seems to work. But my text index is on all three fields (field1, field2, field3), in this case how can I use this ? can you please guide me ?

Comment: Hey . I think your answer worked when I used concatArrays. Can you please update your  comment  so I can mark it as answer. Following is the code i used
{
    "$addFields": {
      "matched-keywords": {
        "$concatArrays": [{
            "$split": [
              "$field1",
              " "
            ]},
              {"$split": [
                "$field2",
              " "
            ]},
              {"$split": [
                "$field3",
              " "
            ]}
        ]
      }
    }
  },

Comment: Also I have another question. What is the meaning of $$word ? why double "$" ?

Comment: Good question. To access the value of the variable "word" prefix the variable name with double dollar signs ($$); i.e. "$$<variable>". [Variables in Aggregation Expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variables-in-aggregation-expressions)